# 'Add Config Transforms' and One Click Publish option not working when upgraded from Visual Studio 2005 to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, upgrade

I just recently upgrade my asp.net web project from visual studio 2005 to visual studio 2010. The upgrade was successful with no problems however im missing some features with this project.  The One Click Publish feature(which is greyed out) in the header area of Visual Studio 2010 and the Add Config Transforms feature which is no where to be seen when you right click on web.config. Any suggestions on how i set this up?  When i create a new web project straight from visual studio 2010, these options work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a web *application* project, or a web *site* project? Web.config transforms are only available in a web application project, as far as I've been able to figure out.