# How do I generate separate config files for different configurations?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

I have multiple configurations and so I need different App.config files for the different environments/configurations.  Question is how do I generate these separate files?  I remember I used to be able to right click on the file and click on something to do it but I don't see anything to do that right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my MVC projects, I can do that by Right clicking on the config file and then selecting `Add Config Transforms`.

That should create new config files for all the different build configurations you have in your solution. For example, if your project has two configurations `Debug` and `Release`. Doing the above for `web.config` should create two new config files, `web.Debug.config` and `web.Release.config`. You can then modify those config files accordingly. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) are instructions on how to do so.

Also, in case you don't have the `Add Config Transform` option in your right click context menu, you can download the [`Web Publish Update`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj161045) for Visual Studio which contains this feature.

If the `Add Config Transform` option appears to be grayed out, here are some suggestions I have found:

1. Do a full rebuild
2. They might already exist - click on `Show All Files` in the `Solution Explorer` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577931/web-config-transformation-option-is-greyed-out)).
3. You might not have multiple configurations defined. ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037072/asp-net-web-application-add-config-transform-grayed-out))
4. Make sure you are working on a `Web Application` project and not a `Web Site` project. ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350276/add-config-transforms-and-one-click-publish-option-not-working-when-upgraded-f))

Edit:
In case you are not working on a web project, you can use the [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) visual studio addin to enable xml transforms for arbitrary xml files. ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004210/app-config-transformation-for-projects-which-are-not-web-projects-in-visual-stud))

Comment: Problem is I don't have the Add Config Transforms option - I used to have it but I've got a new laptop now.  What do I need to install?

Comment: In fact it is not missing it is dissabled

Comment: MVC is installed - yep - mvc 4.

Comment: Apparently you need this http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj161045. Also, how do you know it's disabled?

Comment: When I say disabled I mean the option is there but greyed out and not clickable.

Comment: Oh I see. Do you have multiple configurations defined for your solution? If not, do that by going to `Build -> Configuration Manager`. Also, it could be that those files already exist, Try clicking on "Show All Files" in the solution explorer to check whether they already exist or not.

Comment: I have 7 configurations defined.  They don't exist.  I'mm installing this update.

Comment: Also, I just read in another stackoverflow post that transformation options are only available for `Web Application` projects and not for `Web Site` projects. Make sure you're working on a web application.

Comment: it's actually a console app.

Comment: Try this http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on File. -> Add new Item -> Visual C# Items -> General-> create "Application Configuration file."